# How many entries are created when you make a new directory in *nix?

Tags: filesystems, directory

I am thinking `mkdir ~/a` is either two or three:

- 1 entry for the dir it sits in (`~/a`)
- 1 entry for itself (`cd a && ls .`)
- and/or 1 entry for itself again (`cd a && ls ..`)

Could someone clarify if this is two or three?

Comment: You mind looking at the question again, and clarify; the 2nd and 3rd commands are exactly again.

Comment: It is three - think of `mkdir /test` - `/test` links to itself (`.`) and its parent (`..`), and then `/` now links to `/test`. Indeed, `/test` has two entries inside of it, but three entries total are created.

Answer (score 3):

In an empty directory:

```
% stat .
  File: `.'
  Size: 6               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fe04h/65028d    Inode: 537317737   Links: 2
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: ( 1000/stribika)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2011-02-22 08:47:20.935036074 +0100
Modify: 2011-02-22 08:47:20.935036074 +0100
Change: 2011-02-22 08:47:20.935036074 +0100
 Birth: -
% mkdir foo
% stat .
  File: `.'
  Size: 16              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fe04h/65028d    Inode: 537317737   Links: 3
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: ( 1000/stribika)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2011-02-22 08:47:20.935036074 +0100
Modify: 2011-02-22 08:47:57.465036072 +0100
Change: 2011-02-22 08:47:57.465036072 +0100
 Birth: -
% stat foo
  File: `foo'
  Size: 6               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fe04h/65028d    Inode: 509269      Links: 2
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: ( 1000/stribika)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2011-02-22 08:47:57.465036072 +0100
Modify: 2011-02-22 08:47:57.465036072 +0100
Change: 2011-02-22 08:47:57.465036072 +0100
 Birth: -
```

As you can see there are 2 links to an empty directory. When I create a new one inside it the link count increases to 3. Additionaly there are 2 links to the new directory. The total is 3 new links.

This is because every directory has a link to itself (.) and its parent (..) .

Comment: I like Gilles answer better - a brand-new directory has two links to it, but creating a new directory creates three new entries in the filesystem: `.` and `..` in the new directory, and the actual link to the new directory, in its parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

In the original Unix implementation, in order to keep the filesystem code inside the kernel simple, directory manipulation programs did some extra work: in particular, `mkdir /parent/a` created an entry for `a` in `/parent`, plus an entry called `.` in `a` (pointing to `a` itself) and an entry called `..` in `a` (pointing to `/parent`¹).

Pretty soon the code for `mkdir` and friends moved into the kernel anyway, but the filesystem format kept having explicit `.` and `..` entries, which filesystem traversal code found by name (as opposed to having two special-format pointers in each directory).

Nowadays, some (most?) filesystems fake it: directories don't actually have `.` and `..` entries on the disk, they're generated by the driver. However, from a user's point of view, this is transparent. A directory's link count is still two plus the number of subdirectories (the entry in the parent, the directory's own `.`, and each subdirectory's `..`). In particular, an empty directory has a link count of two (i.e. there are two entries in the filesystem pointing to it), but creating it creates three entries (the third one is `..` which points to the parent).

¹ 
<sub>By reference, not by name. So if you rename `/parent`, `a`'s `..` keeps pointing to `a`'s parent directory, wherever it moves to in the filesystem structure.</sub>